# How to automatically add a button at the end of every sub-heading in mediawiki 1.30?

Tags: button, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm trying to add a button at the end of every subheading automatically in a mediawiki article. For this, I have decided to add the button code on the mediawiki page code(which is seen by ctrl+u). Now, I'm trying to locate the code for a subheading in the mediawiki directory. In which file is the code for sub-heading (or sub-sections) located? Or is there any extension I can use for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for headings is here: https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/1.30.0/php/Parser_8php_source.html#l01607

It would probably be cleaner to try and place a marker in the right position with the [ParserBeforeStrip](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ParserBeforeStrip) hook and then finally replace the marker with your button code with the [ParserAfterTidy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ParserAfterTidy) hook.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to place markers with ParserBeforeStrip?

Comment: Well, you can do a regexp over the text to find headings and then add some magicword in there that you can find again. Later in the ParserAfterTidy hook you just search for whichever magicword you chose.